# Finding Earnings at Time in Incremental Game Style Growth: Closed Form of Breakpoint Finite Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been toying with the math behind incremental games over the last few days and trying to find a non-iterative way to calculate earnings at a specific time in a situation where income increases at earning breakpoints - representing buying new generators or whatever.

The scenario is as follows:

- $a$: Income rate of a single generator
- $b$: Initial cost of a single generator
- $c$: Exponential cost multiplier for each subsequent generator
- $n$: Current number of generators

And since I was plotting this on a graph -

- $x$: Time
- $y$: Total earnings

This means that at any particular time the rate of income is $an$ ($n$ generators each producing $a$) and the cost of the next generator is $b(c^n)$ ($b$ increased by a factor of $c$ for each existing generator), and it's assumed that as soon as available cash reaches that value, a new generator is purchased. Time until the next generator is purchased is this cost divided by the income, so $\frac{b(c^n)}{an}$.

Plotting the earnings iteratively is pretty trivial, since simulating it by timestep just requires adding the income and checking when it's over the price for the next generator.

[**Edit:** The graph itself is a series of straight lines between breakpoints where the earnings reach the point where a new generator can be bought, increasing $n$ by 1. Each segment of the graph can be considered a triangle with a base equal to the time to next purchase, and a height equal to the cost.

[Graph image showing these triangles and overall shape of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbHUs.png)
]

Because we're dealing with total time and earnings the coordinates of the breakpoint where the $n$th generator is purchased can be calculated as the sums of all the generators before it instead:
$$y = \sum_{i=1}^n b(c^i)$$
$$x = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b(c^i)}{ai}$$

[**Edit:** Thanks to the comments I now know these to be better represented as:
$$y = b\sum_{k=1}^n c^k$$
$$x = \frac{b}{a}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c^k}{k}$$
Sorry for being unfamiliar with the proper notation!]

[**More Edit:** I've worked out that $y$ is:
$$y = b\frac{1-c^{n+1}}{1-c}$$
Still not sure how to tackle $x$ though.
]

Now, here's the problem... I have no idea how to use this information to calculate the value of $y$ for a given $x$ when $n$ isn't directly involved. $n$ is clearly tied directly to $x$, but I lack the knowledge about rearranging series that'd be required to eliminate $n$ as a separate term. It's been over a decade since I last took a math class and we didn't go into quite this level of detail when I did.

If I can find the highest breakpoint before $x$, the value of $y$ could be found by interpolating the $y$ values at $n$ and $n+1$ by $x$ but I have no idea how to reach that value from $x$. I got as far as there probably being a $log_c$ involving $n$ and a floor in there somewhere... It would be preferable to find a way which doesn't need that step though, if such a thing exists.

So I ask you all, given just $x$ and the 3 constants $a$, $b$ and $c$, how would I find $y$?

(Edited for clarity based on comments)

Comment: Do you mean: Rate of income is $a_n$ ? So **not** $an$, $a$ multiplied by $n$ ?

Comment: It would be $a$ multiplied by $n$, as there are $n$ generators each producing $a$ income.

Comment: So how I see it, is that you know the value of $x=\frac{b}{a}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c^k}{k}$ and you want to calculate the value of $y=b\sum_{k=1}^n c^k$? (Notice that I changed the indices so that it's easier to read; and also moved the constants in front of the summation) So is that the mathematical problem you are facing? We also assume that $a, b, c$ are known values.

Comment: Yes, I _think_ that's the case, thankyou for rearranging them, I'm a largely self-taught programmer rather than a mathematician and not familiar with this kind of notation at all -  I didn't even know you could pull things outside the sum like that but it makes sense in retrospect. $a$, $b$ and $c$ are known and constant. Those two describe the position of breakpoint $n$ where $n$ increases - the graph between each one is a straight line as $n$ remains the same until the earnings are enough to purchase another generator, so I imagine finding $n$ in terms of $x$ will involve flooring somewhere.

Comment: Notice also that if you have the function
$$
f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^nx^k = x+x^2+x^3+ \ldots+x^n = x \frac{x^n-1}{x-1} 
$$
then the integral is
$$
F_n(x)= \int f_n(x)\,dx = \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \ldots + \frac{x^{n+1}}{n} = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{x^k}{k} = \ldots
$$
There is an expression for the integral, but it involves the hypergeometric function.